# Some question in relative homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

When we consider the pair (X,A) in relative homology, do we assume A is a sub complex of X?

And why don't we just consider X/A instead of (X,A)?

Is there an better advantage to consider (X,A) than X/A? Moreover, can you give some examples that $C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ is different from $C_n(X/A)$ to show the advantages?

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what homology theory you are using. Simplicial homology? Singular homology?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, singular homology

Comment: In that case, it definitely doesn't have to be a subcomplex.

Comment: Consider $X=[0,1]$ and $A=\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{0\}$. $H_1(X/A)\ne H_1(X,A)$. (Also, you almost always get different groups in dimension zero, even for 'good' pairs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: in this answer I assume the singular homology theory.

Sometimes $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$, but not in general. For example, we could consider the pair $(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)$. In order for $H_n(X,A)=\tilde H_n(X/A)$ to be true, we need a neighborhood of $A$ in $X$ which deformation retracts to $A$. This is not true in many cases. For a simple example, let $X=S^2$ and $A=S^2\setminus\{x\}$ where $x$ is any point in $S^1$. The long exact sequence of pairs gives us $$H_2(A)\to H_2(X)\to H_2(X,A)\to H_1(A).$$ We know $H_2(A)=H_1(A)=0$, so $H_2(X,A)=H_2(X)=\mathbb Z$. But $X/A$ is the Sierpinski topological space with two points, which is contractible, so $H_2(X/A)=0$. (Sorry this is an example in the homology groups instead of chain complexes, the chain complexes are harder to describe). The reason we prefer $(X,A)$ to $X/A$ is that a lot of powerful theorems about $(X,A)$ are simply untrue for $X/A$. For example, we do not always get a long exact sequence $$...\to H_n(X)\to H_n(A)\to H_n(X/A)\to H_{n-1}(A)\to...$$

Comment: If A is not a sub complex of X, then  if X=[0,2] with vertex {0,2}, edge[0,2] A=[0,1] with vertex {0,1}, edge[0,1], then what is C0(X)/C0(A)? C0(A) even is not a subgroup of C0(X).

Comment: $C_0(X)$ is the free abelian group generated by all points of $X$. If $A\subset X$, then $C_0(A)$ is clearly a subgroup of $C_0(X)$.

Comment: I should also add that $C_0(A)$ is the free abelian group generated by all points in $A$. Since all points in $A$ are also in $X$, $C_0(A)\subset C_0(X)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense, one more question, why do you consider Hn(X,A)=H̃ n(X/A) instead of Hn(X,A)=Hn(X/A)?

Comment: Simply because the latter is not true. $H_n(X,A)=H_n(X/A)$ in certain conditions for all $n>0$, not when $n=0$. It so happens that $H_0(X,A)=\tilde H_0(X/A)$, and since $H_n(X/A)=\tilde H_n(X/A)$ for $n>0$, we write $H_n(X,A)=\tilde H_n(X/A)$.

Comment: How is $X/A$ discrete? Wouldn't it be homeomorphic to the Sierpiński space?

Comment: @Akiva Hmmm... It is. Isn't $H_2$ still zero, though?

Comment: I believe so. (But I don't have a lot of experience with finite spaces. For any $n$, there are finite spaces with nontrivial homology groups in dimension $n$, if I recall correctly. So they can be weird.)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it is contractible, so it seems we're good.

Answer (score 1):

No, $A$ does not need to be a subcomplex. $A$ is just any subspace of the topological space $X$.

For a very simple counterexample, consider the case when $A = X$.